# gluing together real-analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have two real-analytic functions $f,g$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ respectively. Are there some sufficient conditions for when it is possible to glue these together, i.e., for the function
$$h(x) = \begin{cases}f(x),& x < 0\\
\lim_{y\to 0^-} f(y),& x = 0\\
g(x), &x > 0\end{cases}$$
to be real-analytic? Obviously the limits of all derivatives of $f$ and $g$ must exist and agree at $0$ but this is not enough, as demonstrated by the standard bump function.

Comment: It is necessary and sufficient that there are $a < 0 < b$ such that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ with centre $a$ is larger than $\lvert a\rvert$, and the radius of the Taylor series of $g$ with centre $b$ is larger than $b$, and all derivatives of $f$ and $g$ agree at $0$. Well, that's admittedly kind of obvious, and probably not a useful criterion. But the identity theorem is strong. If you can glue, the cut must have been artificial.

Comment: It seems to me that if both $f$ and $g$ are defined in a small interval around $0$, say $(-a, a)$, then one can indeed glue the two functions $f$ and $g$ together by means of suitable sigmoidal function $\sigma(x)$. As follows: $h(x) = \sigma(x)f(x) + (1-\sigma(x))g(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be pretty hard. Consider the function $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$. This is a $C^\infty$ function that's not analytic at $0$. It is analytic on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$. These two sides join in a $C^\infty$ way at $0$ but fail to be analytic. I suspect there aren't any nice conditions that work that don't involve really gritty details about radii of convergence.